# Use indexed shifters on new bike

Tags: mountain-bike, shifter

I have a 26 inch 24 speed mountain bike.

When I get another bike, can I re-use the Sunrace indexed shifters on the new bike?

It would be a 26 inch bike also.

[image]

Comment: Given that shifters can be had for about $15 a piece, is it even worth the effort of swapping them over? What sort of shifters is the new bike coming with?

Comment: Most bikes in my price range have twist shifters. @Caius Jard

Comment: I'm not sure of the metric for what kind of price range a twist shift implies but if you're intimating that it's a lower spec/cheaper range than trigger, I'd perhaps hazard a suggestion that you may get more out of your money upgrading the bike you have, unless there's something catastophically wrong with it (snapped frame), than buying a whole new one and having a host of components to upgrade (it may be that things cannot just be swapped off your existing one in isolation), You should consider giving a lot more detail on the current and proposed bike/equip level and reasons for change

Comment: I have been upgrading it. 18 speed to 24 speed. Indexed shifters. The front has disc brakes. I would prefer rear disc brakes as well. @Caius Jard

Comment: Might be worth asking a new question then, saying what you have/what you've upgraded and asking for advice on what way to go. It seems like you're asking about buying a whole new bike, of some low level in budget terms, which means you'll get pretty much junk everything, and most of it you'll swap out, so it seems like it might be an overly expensive way to get a crap version of what you still need, y know? eg if your frame is broken, but all the components are good, you could just spend $200 on a reasonable frame not $200 on a low grade bike with its $50 frame and then throw half of it away?

Comment: I disagree with your "crap version of what you still need." My current bike cost $120. And it has lasted over 3000 miles. And it will last many thousands more. @Caius Jard

Comment: Except it didn't cost $120, cos you've upgraded it! One can't claim a bike cost $100 if they then spent $5000 changing the frame, wheels, brakes, gearset... I'm kinda confused why you're even asking your question. Maybe 8 speed cassettes will be obsolete by the time you wear your bike out, mooting the entire question. The way you worded it it sounded like your bike was in imminent need of replacement, now you're saying you don't perceive needing to replace the bike in any foreseeable time frame..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shifters don't care about wheel/rim size.  They only care about how many gears there are to shift across, and once you hit 10~11 speed then it also matters whether the bike is using a road or MTB groupset.

**Answer** Yes you can move shifters to another bike, as long as the speeds match, and the handlebar diameter is the same.

Your bike is a 3x on the front and a 8x on the rear, so the new bike would have to be the same.

If you have integrated shifters (where the brake lever and the shifter are in the same unit) then the brakes will have to match too - you couldn't use brake levers from V-Brakes with disk brakes.

---

<sup>There are some situations where you could get away with a mismatch, but they'd be unusual, like using your 8 speed rear shifter on a 6 or 7 speed rear block, and having one or two dead positions.  Not recommended.</sup>

Comment: By speeds, is that the same as gears? @Criggie

Comment: @fixit7 yes - the terms "speeds" and "gears" are mostly interchangeable. You have 3 front chainrings multiplied by 8 rear cogs in your cassette/freewheel/block  and that is 24 total speeds/gears/combinations.

Comment: The derailleurs must also match the shifters. Most Sram shifters doesn't work well with Shimano derailleurs and vice versa.

Comment: @mikes I have Sunrace shifters.

Comment: You assume the Sunrace shifters are Shimano compatible (which is very likely true), but would have been worth mentioning. OP can check their derailleurs of course

Comment: The shifters were recommended and installed by a bike shop. @Argenti Apparatus